# queue revprop for commit

Tags: svn

I would like to queue a revprop for the *next* commit.

I can do `svn commit -m "some commit log" --with-revprop "myprop=some value"`, but I don't want to have to include the revprop in the commit commandline.  Essentially I want to have it as part of the working copy state like all the revisioned tree, text, and property changes are.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for "svn propset"

Comment: Can you give an example commandline using svn propset which sets a *revprop* for the *next* commit?  I have not found a way to do that.